# How can I play a sound when my meteor server restarts?

Tags: meteor

I have only one monitor and I find it hard keeping track of all the windows, and on top of that, I have a slow PC.
I am usually at my text editor, not seeing if the changes were loaded by Meteor.js. Is there anyway to play a sound when my meteor server restarts because of changes?

Bonus points: a different sound when there's an error preventing the startup.

Edit: I'm using Windows 7, but I'd also want to know how to do it on Mac and Linux.

Comment: Can you update your question with the operating system that you are using?

Comment: Updated the question with the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use node for this:

meteor add meteorhacks:npm

Then run your project with `meteor` to create the `packages.json` file in your root directory

Add the below to the package.json so it looks something like this:

```
{
    "play": "0.5.0"
}
```

Create a file on your desktop, a sound, e.g `sound.wav`

And play it on startup: (server side code):

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
     var play = Meteor.npmRequire('play').Play();

    // play with a callback
    play.sound('~/Desktop/sound.wav', function() { });



   //If you want to know when the player has defintely started playing
   play.on('play', function (valid) {
     console.log('I just started playing!');
   });

  //If you want to know if this can't play for some reason
  play.on('error', function () {
     console.log('I can't play!');
  });
});
```

It should work on mac and windows too, just make sure you use the correct path, you may be better off with an absolute path to the file `C:\Users....wav`

You will need one of the following cli players to play the sound:

- afplay
- mplayer (Easiest installed on os x with brew install mplayer, on windows this may help: http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/windows.html)
- mpg123
- mpg321
- play

You can install any, so long as the platform can run one it should be ok.. If you download the raw binary for any of them be sure to add the directory the executables are in to your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Seems to be broken. Console says 'Object doesn't have method Play' https://github.com/Marak/play.js/issues/10